# Combining multiple datasets with different shapes from differen hdf5 files into one single hdf5 file

Tags: python, image, hdf5

I am working with 2D medical images in python stored in multiple `hdf5` files with different shapes (e. g. `[30,99,761,761], [20,30,99,761,761]` and ..) and I want to combine all of them into a 3-dimensional array into a single hdf5 file (with shape [n,761,761]). At the moment I am doing this by reading each image `[761,761]` from each dataset of each hdf5 file and then writing the image into one single file. This process takes more than `24` hours since there are around `40000` images and I assume this the least optimized solution. Is there a faster way to selectively slice and copy data from an hdf5 files into another one?

Here is the code.
first creates the File that I want to combine the images from other files into:

```
ip_augmented_shape = (((num_rotations)*(1+3+num_translations)*len(addrs)),img.shape[0],img.shape[1])
ip_augmented = h5py.File(ip_augmented_path, mode='w')
ip_augmented.create_dataset("data1", ip_augmented_shape,np.int32)
ip_augmented.create_dataset("Index1",(ip_augmented_shape[0],num_classes), np.float32)
ip["Index1"][...] = labels 

print("Creating the data set \n")
counter = 0
pbar = tqdm(total=ip_augmented_shape[0])
```

And now reading images one by one from each file and writing it to the target file. There is always a index for each image that get copied as well.

```
for i in range(ip_rotated_flipped_h_shape[0]):
    for j in range(ip_rotated_flipped_h_shape[1]):
        ip_augmented['data1'][counter] = ip_rotated_flipped_h['images'][i][j]
        ip_augmented['Index1'][counter]= ip_rotated_flipped_h['Index1'][i][j]
        counter = counter+1
        pbar.update(1)

for i in range(ip_rotated_flipped_h_shape[0]):
    for j in range(ip_rotated_flipped_h_shape[1]):
        ip_augmented['data1'][counter] = ip_rotated_flipped_h['images'][i][j]
        ip_augmented['Index1'][counter]= ip_rotated_flipped_h['Index1'][i][j]
        counter = counter+1
        pbar.update(1)

for i in range(ip_rotated_flipped_v1_shape[0]):
    for j in range(ip_rotated_flipped_v1_shape[1]):
        ip_augmented['data1'][counter] = ip_rotated_flipped_v1['images'][i][j]
        ip_augmented['Index1'][counter]= ip_rotated_flipped_v1['Index1'][i][j]
        counter = counter+1
        pbar.update(1)

for i in range(ip_rotated_flipped_v2_shape[0]):
    for j in range(ip_rotated_flipped_v2_shape[1]):
        ip_augmented['data1'][counter] = ip_rotated_flipped_v2['images'][i][j]
        ip_augmented['Index1'][counter]= ip_rotated_flipped_v2['Index1'][i][j]     
        counter = counter+1
        pbar.update(1)

for i in range(ip_rotated_translated_shape[0]):
    for j in range(ip_rotated_translated_shape[1]):
        for k in range(ip_rotated_translated_shape[2]):
            ip_augmented['data1'][counter] = ip_rotated_translated['images'][i][j][k]
            ip_augmented['Index1'][counter]= ip_rotated_translated['Index1'][i][j][k]
            counter = counter+1
            pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: Please provide a working example. There are many things that have a bad impact on performance, but without looking at your code it is hard to provide a better solution. (also add how do you wan't to read the data afterwards -> important for chunk-dims)

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for your reply. I added the code to my question.